# VBA Code for indenting cells based on a specific cell value

Tags: excel, vba, indentation

In Excel column "C" has values of either Yes or No.  If the value is "No" then I want to indent the value of column "D" 2 indents if possible.  How would one accomplish this?

Comment: Can you give me a solution about the question below?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30021271/vba-windows-api-for-automating-external-app-using-ms-spy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
Sub IndentD()
    For Each r In Intersect(Range("C:C"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        If r.Text = "No" Then
            r.Offset(0, 1).InsertIndent 2
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
For Each i in Sheets("sheetname").Range("C1:C100")  ' change to last row number
    If i.Value = "No" Then
        i.Offset(0,1).InsertIndent 2 ' Offset selection from column C to D
    End If
Next i
```

**Explanation:** `For each` loops through the cells in column C. For every round of the loop, the current cell in column C is assigned to the variable `i`. You then check, whether that cell's value is "No" and if yes, you add the two "indents" to the neighboring cell in column D. (using the `Offset(rows, cols)` function. `Offset(0,1)` = same row, one column to the right)